# How to communicate stdout between Ruby and Python with a multiprocessing Python script

Tags: linux, pipe, multiprocessing, named-pipes

In Ruby, I'm a running command which is a python script that returns its output to standard out.

```
Open3.pipeline_r(command) do |out, wait_thread|
   out.each_line do |o|
    # process some stdout from python 
   end
end
```

This worked OK, until I wanted to introduce multiple processes to parallelize the python process.

I wanted to add instrumentation/logging to the python process such the new python process uses multiprocessing to perform logging in a second lighter weight process while the main process is running and communicates through the multiprocessing Queue. The main process takes 100% cpu of one cpu on a multicore machine and little memory, so I'm experimenting with breaking this up into multiple processes to take advantage of more cores.

The problem is now the Ruby process can read the stdout from the main process which is doing the work, but it can't read stdout from the new python process.

From what I understand from reading the docs on various subprocess libraries `Ruby will run the command as a child connected to Ruby with a pipe.` I'm unclear how to read the stdout from the new python subprocess, which ideally would do all the logging and print statements.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-pipe

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn

In this context Ruby is Rails runner and is used to report back the results over http with an api to another service.  The multiprocess python script is on the same machine in the same project folder as the Rails project.

Appreciate any suggestions on what direction to follow.  Thanks! Laura

Edit:
I like your suggest @tadman, what I'm trying to do is understand this current architecture and finding that I am confused between pipes, named pipes, and locked pipes.  Python seems to work really nicely with Linux.  Since Linux seems to be all about pipes and this implementation is running on Linux I'd like to understand more about what is going on.  I'm trying to research to be able to talk about the pros and cons of this approach vs. using a socket or other implementation. :)

From http://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php

Generally there are two kinds of pipes:

- anonymous pipes

and

- named pipes

Anonymous pipes exist solely within processes and are usually used in combination with forks.

Questions: The pipe between Ruby and Python is an anonymous pipe because it's forking a new process? The pipes inside the python processing also use anonymous pipes in multiprocessing.SimpleQueue the author says is a locked pipe? I misspoke and called it a named pipe and got jumped on for making this mistake.

Comment: Instead of named pipes which can be hard to wrangle between two totally different environments, you could try TCP or UNIX sockets. Open3 is a good library for managing subprocesses, but two-way communication can be tricky to coordinate. What you need is an IPC (Inter-Process Communication) strategy that works with both Ruby and Python. The cheap and cheerful way is to serialize things as JSON and just fire JSON objects back and forth, or use [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org) to give it a bit more structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of this architecture.  The 'architect' says oh this is just a Pipe.  And from the python multiprocessing SimpleQueue module the author says 'Simplified Queue type -- really just a locked pipe.'  I'd like to understand, what does that mean? :)

Comment: Maybe this is my confusion, from the multiprocessing library it looks like it would be a named pipe if it were on Windows: A higher level module for using sockets (or Windows named pipes)